# The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError

Tags: xconnect

We are getting below error in sitecore 9.0.2 version on cd environment for getting interactions from xdb using *xconnect*

In connectionstring for **CD** below entry was there

```
 <add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://qa.collection" /> -
```

After comment we replaced with entry from cm connection string which is as below

```
<add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://qa.collectionsearch" />
```

After replace error is not coming, Can someone tell should **CD** have only xconnect **collection** and not **search** connection string?

Error Log:

> The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func 1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func 1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.GetBatchEnumeratorSync[TEntity](IAsyncQueryable`1 asyncQueryable, Int32 defaultBatchSize)
>      at isango.Foundation.Analytics_JF2.Services.AnalyticsTrackingService.GetFilterInteractionsByMerchandisingAsync(Guid pageEvent, Int32 days, String destinationIdentifier, String categoryIdentifier, String attractionIdentifier, String country, Int32 count)

Code snippet where error is coming:

```
 using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
       IAsyncQueryable<Interaction> queryable = client.Interactions
                        .Where(x => x.EndDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(days) && x.Events.Any(y=>y.DefinitionId == pageEventId && y.Data == categoryto_filter && y.DataKey == country));

       var enumerable = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync();

       if (enumerable.TotalCount <= 0)
       {
             queryable = client.Interactions
                         .Where(x => x.EndDateTime >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(days) && x.Events.Any(y => y.DefinitionId == pageEventId && y.Data == categoryto_filter));
                        enumerable = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync();
       }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any error in the xConnect logs?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add an additional param for the XConnect.Client.Configuration for the cd node?

```
<param desc="searchConnectionStringName">xconnect.collection</param>
```

I had to add this in my 9.1.1 instance for the cd system.

Before (CD):

```
     <clientconfig type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration"
                    singleInstance="true"
                    role:require="ContentDelivery or Processing or Reporting and !ContentManagement and !Standalone">
        <param desc="clientModel" ref="xconnect/runtime" />
        <param desc="collectionConnectionStringName">xconnect.collection</param>
        <param desc="configurationConnectionStringName">xconnect.collection</param>
      </clientconfig>
```

Patch:

```
  <xconnect>
      <clientconfig type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration"
                    singleInstance="true"
                    role:require="ContentDelivery or Processing or Reporting and !ContentManagement and !Standalone">                    
            <param desc="searchConnectionStringName" patch:after="param[@desc='clientModel']">xconnect.collection</param>
      </clientconfig>
    </xconnect>
```

After (CD):

```
 <clientconfig type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration"
                singleInstance="true"
                role:require="ContentDelivery or Processing or Reporting and !ContentManagement and !Standalone">
    <param desc="clientModel" ref="xconnect/runtime" />
<param desc="searchConnectionStringName">xconnect.collection</param>
    <param desc="collectionConnectionStringName">xconnect.collection</param>
    <param desc="configurationConnectionStringName">xconnect.collection</param>
  </clientconfig>
```

Comment: Hi, I have added this patch after then the above error started came, before that some other error was coming.

Comment: I got this working by adding a entry for search collection in CD instances connection string file and calling the specific entry from code.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding a entry for search collection in CD instances connection string file and calling the specific entry from code